# Hibernate ManyToOne mapping not on PKey

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i have some entities:

```
@Entity
public class Event{

    @Id    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    private long eventId;   

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "host_id")  
    private Host host;
}

@Entity
public class Host{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")   
    private long id;   

    @Column(name = "host_id")
    private long hostId;
}

@Repository
public class EventDao{       

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   @Transactional
   public List<Event> findEventAfterId(long eventId, long hostId){
      Query q=em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id>? AND host_id=?, Event.class);
      q.setParameter(1, eventId);
      q.setParameter(2, hostId);      
      return (List<Event>)q.getResultList();
   }    
}
```

I am trying to get events from this native query:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id>4442 AND host_id=35;
```

And get this exception  `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find entity.Host with id 35` But in my DB i have host with host_id 35. How can i map my event entity to host with host_id column?? Thank you.

UPD:

```
   Query q=em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id>? AND host_id=?, Event.class);
    q.setParameter(1, eventId);
    q.setParameter(2, hostId);      
    return (List<Event>)q.getResultList();
```

Here is full exception:

```
    javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find monitoring.reporter.entity.Host with id 35
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:181)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:218)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:274)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:989)
 at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
 at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1114)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
 at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)
 at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
```

Comment: give me all classes and full exception stack trace I can help you..

Comment: Your host class doesn't make any sense. Is it a parent child relationship with itself? If so you need to tell hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for SQLInjection

```
Query q=em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id>:event_id AND host_id=:host_id, Event.class);
      q.setParameter("event_id", eventId);
      q.setParameter("host_id", hostId);
```

Comment: My bad, i have  @Column(name = "event_id")

Comment: Not, yet, my SQL script is correct, but when i trying to execute (List<Event>) q.getResultList() - i get exception EntityNotFoundException

Comment: Have you check your DB for SELECT * FROM event WHERE eventId>4442;

Comment: Yes, when i am using q.getResultList() without hibernate mapping to list of entities, i am getting the result

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is too small, to explain it clearly I have to write lot of theory here, any way the good news here is I have enough patience to write all theory here.

Let me start with Event class, In Event class you have Host and Event is pointing to primary key of Host.

In Host class the primary key name is 'id', but in Event class that corresponding column name is host_id.

finally you table structure is like below

[image]

In Event class host_id is present but that is pointing to primary key of Host class i.e. id

So Event's host_id is pointing to Host's id column, now lets say in Host table id column is consisting 1 because it is auto incremented,and host_id=35 according to you.

But in Event table host_id is pointing to Host tables id whose value is 1.
but your query is searching for host_id=35 in Event table.
To avoid this issue, In Host class you have to make host_id primary key and don't generate is automatically, assign manual value to host_id. the corresponding classes you can see below:

```
@Entity
public class Event{

   @Id    
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
   @Column(name = "event_id")
   private long eventId;   

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "host_id")  
   private Host host;
}

@Entity
public class Host{

   @Column(name = "id")   
   private long id;   
   @Id
   @Column(name = "host_id")
   private long hostId;
}

@Repository
public class EventDao{       

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   @Transactional
   public List<Event> findEventAfterId(long eventId, long hostId){
      Query q=em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id>? AND host_id=?, Event.class);
      q.setParameter(1, eventId);
      q.setParameter(2, hostId);      
      return (List<Event>)q.getResultList();
   }    
}
```